# Selecting Subdocument array list only in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

My Group Collection Goes like this

```
[
{
    "_id": "55fdbaa7457aa1b9bd7f7cf7",
    "group_name":"Tango Charli",
    "group_desc":"This group is for chatting",
    "group_admins": [
        {
            "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
            "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
            "name": "James",
        },
        {
            "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
            "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
            "name": "James",
        }
    ]
},

{
    "_id": "55fdbaa7457aa1b9bd7f8de8",
    "group_name":"Love zone",
    "group_desc":"This group is for making love and chatting",
    "group_admins": [
        {
            "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
            "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
            "name": "Mike",
        },
        {
            "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
            "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
            "name": "alice",
        }
    ]
},

]
```

I want to list the group admins of particular group

For this I am using follwing query

```
groupModel.find({_id:55fdbaa7457aa1b9bd7f7cf7},'group_admins -_id',function(err,groupDetails){

    if(err)
    {
        res.json({
            "isError":true,
            "error":{
                "status":1042,
                "message":err
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        res.json(groupDetails);
    }
}
);//end of groupModel find
```

It gives following output

```
[
    {
        "group_admins": [
            {
                "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
                "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
                "name": "James",
            },
            {
                "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
                "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
                "name": "James",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

but I want output in following format

```
[
{
    "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
    "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
    "name": "James",
},
{
    "_id": "55ff7fca8d3f6607114dc57d",
    "user_id": "55ff7fca8d3f7607114dc57e",
    "name": "James",
}
]
```

How can I do this , Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for one record, you should use **findOne()** instead of **find()**. Then access the group_admins property of that. i.e.

```
groupModel.findOne({_id:55fdbaa7457aa1b9bd7f7cf7},'group_admins -_id',function(err,groupDetails){
    res.json(groupDetails['group_admins']);
});
```

Comment: hello chriskely, Thanks for response and pointing me the correct ways....   your unedited answer  res.json(groupDetails.shift()['group_admins']); is working and producing result as I wanted.... 
   This answer  res.json(groupDetails['group_admins']); doesn't work... but I modified it as  res.json(groupDetails[0]['group_admins']); now working perfectly.....
  Thank you once again

Comment: @Jorin : You are misreading my edit. You need to use findOne() instead of find(). The reason I edited is because findOne is the right tool for the job since you are selecting by id you only ever want one result returned.

Comment: Oh.. sorry, you had used findOne(),....... ya, for findOne() ..res.json(groupDetails['group_admins']); is working and for find() ...res.json(groupDetails[0]['group_admins']);.......... once again  thank you...

Comment: No problem. I would also recommend using toObject() to send less data over the wire (actually I will update the answer). Also don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Since this is my first question in stackoverflow , It says I need 15 reputation to mark it as answer.... :( .